# Integrability of $\frac{x \log(x)}{(1+x)^{2}}$ on $(1, \infty)$

Tags: integration, lebesgue-integral

> **Question:** Is $\frac{x \log(x)}{(1+x)^{2}}$ Lebesgue-integrable on $(1, \infty)$?

I am not sure how to approach this problem, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What do you think? Is it Lebesgue integrable? It is positive and continuous so you may ask is it improper Riemann integrable? Is that easier for you?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

Since $x\geq 1$, 
$$\frac{x\log(x)}{(1+x)^2}\geq \frac{\log(x)}{4x}.$$

Comment: Isn't this inequality equivalent to $x^{2} \geq 4(1+x)^{2}$ (since $\log(x) \geq 0$ and $x \geq 0$) which does not hold for $x \geq 1$?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/1022834)

Comment: @Taroccoesbrocco: could you explain ? It totally answer the question and show that the integral is $+\infty $ (and thus doesn't converge). If you make reference to@Shashi comment, since $\frac{x\log(x)}{(1+x)^2}\geq 0$ whenever $x\geq 1$, Lebesgue integrability is equivalent to the convergence of the improper integral.

Comment: @Euclidean: if $x\geq 1$, then $1+x\leq 2x$ and thus $\frac{1}{(1+x)^2}\leq \frac{1}{4x^2}$.